# Supporting Documents in DocuSign signing request

Tags: docusignapi

We have a requirement wherein we need to include the additional attachment/supporting documents in the signing request. However, this does not need to be part of the document to be signed - but additional documents which customer would like to be part of the email notification that goes out to signers.

Also, would it be possible to include this document for selected signers only.

Business Case:

- We have multiple internal and external signers - some of whom are senior folks who does not go through the entire document but sign based on an executive summary
- However, this is an internal document and thus needs to be sent only to the internal signers only and should not be included as part of the signing document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include documents in the envelope that do not require signature. IF you want some form of acknowledgement that it was viewed/read/accepted, you can set it as a Supplemental Document.

For the internally view able document, leverage Document Visibility as a way to make certain documents in an envelope only visible to specific recipients of said envelope. This would allow you do add Documents A (customer facing), B (customer facing), and C (internal facing only) for example to an envelope, but only internal recipients on the envelope would be able to see document C.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Can you please point me in direction where I can see more details of how to leverage document visibility in API?